# Getting IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR while setting keycloak as External Identity provider

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, idp

I have two Keycloak instances, A is an IdP for B. From the login screen of B, this works as it should.
However, I can’t get IDP Initiated SSO from A to B to work. I filled the "IDP Initiated SSO URL Name” field with a name (say “bbbbb”) in A.
When I try to navigate to: http://aaaaa/auth/realms/his/protocol/saml/clients/bbbbb
I always end up with the following logging:

22:42:02,993 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-23) Authorization code is not valid. Code: null
22:42:02,994 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-23) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=staleCodeMessage
22:42:02,994 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-23) staleCodeMessage

Which in itself is not surprising, because indeed, there is no Authorization code in play here, but that’s the whole idea of IDP Initiated SSO, no?

What must I do to get this to work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, this happens if you use the same realm name in both Keycloak instances.